Row and column draggable card using react beautiful dnd both rows and columns can be multiple (Reference : Clickup Swimlane)
So i want create a dnd structure like row and column drop its more like task management and below provided its basic column dnd and i need implement with row and column so initial tasks structure can be any structure,so they can drag a task and put in another set of column which will change the task due date or status like this it will be
const initialTasks = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Task 1",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Task 2",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Task 3",
  },
];

    <div className="App">
      <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
        <Droppable droppableId="tasks">
          {(provided) => (
            <div ref={provided.innerRef} {...provided.droppableProps}>
              {tasks.map((task, index) => (
                <Draggable
                  key={task.id}
                  draggableId={task.id.toString()}
                  index={index}
                >
                  {(provided) => (
                    <div
                      {...provided.draggableProps}
                      {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                      ref={provided.innerRef}
                    >
                      <div>{task.title}</div>
                    </div>
                  )}
                </Draggable>
              ))}
              {provided.placeholder}
            </div>
          )}
        </Droppable>
      </DragDropContext>
    </div>
  );<kbd>your text</kbd>

